# How to get a single list of items from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like

```
ID     Values
"ron"  ['1','2']
"ron1" ['10']
"john" []
```

and I want an output list to be like

```
output_list=['1','2','10']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
sum(df['Values'].tolist(),[])
Out[603]: ['1', '2', '10']
```